# Absolutely position n children in a relative manner?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working on a custom drop down list in which I want the parent to be relatively positioned inside the page. I then want all of the children of the drop down list (the list items), to be ignored by the rest of the page to simulate a `select` element. The first thought I had is to position the children with JavaScript via something similar to the following pseudo code:

```
function positionChildren() {
    var ddl = document.getElementById("myDDL");
    var items = ddl.getElementsByTagName("LI");
    var bottom = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        items[i].style.top = bottom + 5 + "px";
        bottom += items[i].height;
    }
}
```

Where the parent would have `position: relative` and each child would have `position: absolute` and thus would be ignored by the rest of the content there.

However, I not only think that it's not that simple, but I also believe there is probably a way to do it with pure CSS, so I've come to the place where masters reside for help.

Here is what I have so far for some clarity:

```js
function openDropDown(dropDownList) {
 dropDownList.classList.toggle("selecting");
}
```

```css
* {
 transition: 0.3s all linear;
}
html,
body {
 margin: 0;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #319;
 background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #b0a, #319);
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #b0a, #319);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.primary-content {
 height: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 15px;
 color: #fff;
 overflow-y: auto;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
}

/* DDL Specific Styles Start Here */
.drop-down-list {
 position: relative;
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
 padding-right: 5px;
 min-width: 300px;
 text-align: left;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
  overflow-y: auto;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
.drop-down-list:after {
 content: "\21AC";
 position: absolute;
 top: -5px;
 right: 5px;
 font-size: 30px;
 color: #555;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.drop-down-list.selecting:after {
 -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(90deg);
 transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(90deg);
}
.drop-down-list.selecting {
 max-height: 60%;
 overflow-y: auto;
}
.drop-down-list > li {
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
 color: #555;
 padding: 2px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
 cursor: pointer;
}
.drop-down-list > li.selected {
 background-color: rgba(20, 200, 255, 0.95);
 color: #fff;
}
.drop-down-list:not(.selecting) > li.selected {
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
 color: #555;
}
.drop-down-list:not(.selecting) > li.selected:hover {
 background-color: #fff;
}
.drop-down-list:not(.selecting) > li:not(.selected) {
 height: 0;
 line-height: 0;
 font-size: 0;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 opacity: 0;
}
.drop-down-list > li:hover {
 background-color: #fff;
}
.drop-down-list > li.selected:hover {
 background-color: #3cf;
}
```

```html
<div id="primary-content" class="primary-content">
  <p class="lead">Click the option to expand the children out.</p>
 <ul class="drop-down-list" onclick="openDropDown(this);">
  <li>Option 1</li>
  <li>Option 2</li>
  <li>Option 3</li>
  <li class="selected">Option 4</li>
  <li>Option 5</li>
  <li>Option 6</li>
  <li>Option 7</li>
  <li>Option 8</li>
  <li>Option 9</li>
  <li>Option 10</li>
  <li>Option 11</li>
  <li>Option 12</li>
  <li>Option 13</li>
 </ul>
 <p class="lead">This paragraph is to simulate content below the drop down to ensure that page content isn't pushed around when the control expands.</p>
</div>
```

How can I position all of the children of my drop down list, relative to the parent, but where they are ignored by the rest of the page?

- The result must be cross browser compatible.

  - I support IE, Edge, Firefox, Chrome, and Safari.
  - I can manually add support for browsers, but the accepted answer has to at least be capable of being expanded.
  - For example, if a feature is in no way supported by any of my supported browsers (such as `position: sticky` not being supported by IE), then I cannot use that feature, and thus the answer shouldn't either.
- Pure CSS is preferred.

  - JavaScript will be accepted if no pure CSS solution is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there - you basically just needed a wrapper around your `ul`.

Some notes:

- making a selection will always toggle the dropdown closed. You'll need to use `e.stopPropagation()` if you want to address that
- the dropdown can go off of the bottom of the page. Playing with the `ul`'s height and letting it scroll when open should help
- the dropdown is not accessible at all

```js
function openDropDown(dropDownList) {
 dropDownList.classList.toggle("selecting");
}
```

```css
* {
 transition: 0.3s all linear;
}
html,
body {
 margin: 0;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #319;
 background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #b0a, #319);
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #b0a, #319);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.primary-content {
 height: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 15px;
 color: #fff;
 overflow-y: auto;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
}

/* DDL Specific Styles Start Here */
.drop-down {
  width: 300px;
  height: 3em;
}

.drop-down-list {
 position: relative;
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
 padding-right: 5px;
 min-width: 300px;
 text-align: left;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
}
.drop-down-list:after {
 content: "\21AC";
 position: absolute;
 top: -5px;
 right: 5px;
 font-size: 30px;
 color: #555;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.drop-down-list.selecting:after {
 -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(90deg);
 transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(90deg);
}
.drop-down-list.selecting {
 max-height: 60%;
 position: absolute;
}
.drop-down-list > li {
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
 color: #555;
 padding: 2px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
 cursor: pointer;
}
.drop-down-list > li.selected {
 background-color: rgba(20, 200, 255, 0.95);
 color: #fff;
}
.drop-down-list:not(.selecting) > li.selected {
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
 color: #555;
}
.drop-down-list:not(.selecting) > li.selected:hover {
 background-color: #fff;
}
.drop-down-list:not(.selecting) > li:not(.selected) {
 height: 0;
 line-height: 0;
 font-size: 0;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 opacity: 0;
}
.drop-down-list > li:hover {
 background-color: #fff;
}
.drop-down-list > li.selected:hover {
 background-color: #3cf;
}
```

```html
<div id="primary-content" class="primary-content">
  <p class="lead">Click the option to expand the children out.</p>
  <div class="drop-down">
    <ul class="drop-down-list" onclick="openDropDown(this);">
      <li>Option 1</li>
      <li>Option 2</li>
      <li>Option 3</li>
      <li class="selected">Option 4</li>
      <li>Option 5</li>
      <li>Option 6</li>
      <li>Option 7</li>
      <li>Option 8</li>
      <li>Option 9</li>
      <li>Option 10</li>
      <li>Option 11</li>
      <li>Option 12</li>
      <li>Option 13</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
 <p class="lead">This paragraph is to simulate content below the drop down to ensure that page content isn't pushed around when the control expands.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: An additional note - symbols for the dropdown indicator are cool, but css triangles for dropdown indicators are really cool: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/